Creating a conditional field in DocuSign
I have searched for making a conditional field in DocuSign for SSN or EIN. I found the answer for creating a drop down filed and then based on that it will display the field for SSN or EIN. I can do it for SSN, but when I try for EIN it won't let me select that field again. Can someone be more specific?
I tired putting a drop-down field for them to select and once selected either the SSN field or the EIN field would appear. I can't get them both to work. Only one.

As a follow up, when  am doing validation, the SSN is in the drop down list, but what would I have to put in for a custom validation for the EIN number which is two digits, a dash, and 7 digits. Thanks again

Figured it out. Thank you for providing this forum to learn so much. Although, I still would like to know how to do the custom validation for EIN
